# How do I determine if a foundation pillar is load bearing?

Tags: foundation, load-bearing

We bought our house in 2021, the previous owner had the foundation replaced a year or two before we bought the house.

The person who did the foundation got the new foundation higher than the older one. I believe that we can adjust the pillar going from the crawl space to the attic which would level out the house on the inside plus balance the weight out equally.

Are there any tips on what to look for to know if the pillar is load bearing?

Comment: Please take a few moments to reread what you've typed pretending that you know _nothing_ about the situation and see if _you_ understand it. There's no formatting, run on sentences, no formatting, spelling errors (we'll blame those on the phone). What's a "half fast" foundation? Does that mean it's not quick, but not too slow?

Comment: I have fixed your list, just to show you, how much better it looks already.  Please fix teh rest of teh formatting.

Comment: Are you sure this “brick pillar” isn’t an old chimney? Are there any other posts/columns in the crawl space?

Comment: Even if it's a chimney, it could be/have been load bearing. Mine was before subsidence forced installation of laly columns.

Comment: There are degrees of load bearing. If a carrier beam or load bearing ridge beam from either side, for instance, are supported by the column, then that would be the max weight, probably. If the column (or chimney) supports joists that run into it instead of the typical load bearing wall, then that would be the minimum weight (beside zero), probably. Is there a bearing wall candidate in the column's neighborhood? Is there a carrier beam or beams? I would expect that the rafters are tied, but what's going on in the attic around the column? You can see it well up there, right?

Comment: Or is the house so skinny in the joist spanning direction that a carrier beam and/or load bearing wall is unnecessary? You'll need to provide a lot more detail about the structure, and if it's load bearing you'll get an answer. If it's not load bearing, then you'll probably get "it's probably not load bearing, but you better call an engineer." Part of the problem is that I can't judge your competence for changing the elevation of substantial weight in your home, where I'm afraid of participating in a life threatening catastrophe.